# Rails: A form to create and edit more than one resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A "user" has_many "foods" through "favorite_foods".

```
users
email:string first_name:string last_name:string

foods
name:string 

favorite_foods
user:references food:references
```

How can I make a single form to edit a "user" and their "favorite_foods"? Is there a Rails convention for which controller#action this should go in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `nested_form` gem for this purpose.

Reference: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Also, refer to the following two screencasts from the author of above gem:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

> **Note**: I am not sure if the above screencasts are still valid.
>   **Note**: Do go through all other tutorials/screencasts on that site, if you have not done so already. Will be really useful :)